# Finding the equation of a quadratic with 2 points and a known slope. (SPLINES)

Tags: quadratics, spline

Sketch the spline of degree 2 with value 0.5 at x = 2.5 and the values 1, 1, 0, 0 at t0, . . . , t3, respectively. (t0=0, t1=2, t2=3, and t3=5)
What is the value of the spline at x = 1 and 4?
What I don't understand is how to find both the quadratics shown for 0

[image: Showing the correct answer parts iii and iv]

Comment: What I don't understand is how to find both the quadratics shown for 0<x<2 and 3<x<5. I understand you have 2 points for each and a given slope which has to match the slope of the interval 2<x<3 which is -1. Please could someone help me

Comment: Extremely unclear IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first quadratic is $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. That implies that $p'(x)=2ax+b$. You require $p(0)=p(2)=1$ and $p'(2)=-1$, so $c=1,4a+2b+c=1$ and $4a+b=-1$. Hence $a=-\frac{1}{2},b=1,c=1$ and the quadratic is $1+\frac{1}{2}x(2-x)$. An exactly similar approach works for the second quadratic.